# Test SQL Server Connection without creating database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework code-first approach. I want to develop a form in which user will enter SQL Server detail like server name, user ID, password and database name which will be created by code first.

But before creating a database I want to test the connection to SQL Server without creating any test database. Is it possible to test SQL Server connection without creating any database?

I tried creating a test database in that server and verify but this method is quite not acceptable as creating a test database and then delete it is not the solution to the issue.

Please provide any logic that can test SQL Server connection without database.

Comment: check my edited answer.

Comment: You can check connectivity to `master` database.

Answer (score 1):

Look for an open listener on port 1433 (the default port). If you get any response after creating a tcp connection there, the server's probably up.-

```
         try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("Your Host", 1433);
            Console.WriteLine("Connection open");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection not open");
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide any sample code or url that can help me out?